# How to hide pdf download option of browser when I click on pdf link in php or using .htaccess file

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, pdf

Here is my pdf image with link

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5h7S.png)

then I click on that pdf link and open that pdf, how I will hide that pdf download option of browser.

I tried to resolved this problem using .htaccess but not getting result
Actually I don't have control on this pdf link that's why I can't disable download option using php, javascript and .htaccess

I also tried to parse that pdf into html but I stuck.

Please give me any suggestion for resolving this issue

Comment: Simple answer: you can't do it this way. When the user is viewing the PDF in their Browser, they already have a local copy of it. So if you don't want them to download it, you would have to deny access to the pdf itself, but that would mean they also can't view it in their browser.

Comment: _"I don't have control on this pdf link"_ - So you're asking how to disable the download option of a PDF that's not even under your control?

Comment: use Google Books if you want to show your pdf without download using iframe :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tobias F.
But my main aim is to view pdf only

Comment: @SNTiwari N Tiwari Thanks for resolving my issued for web browser But still  mobile browser shows the download option